# Why cookies prefixed with __Host- must set path to /?

Tags: security, cookies

[Cookie prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#cookie_prefixes) established that cookies with a name prefixed by `__Host-` must:

1. Contain the `Secure` attribute.
2. Not contain a `Domain` attribute.
3. Contain a `Path` attribute with a value of `/`.

Otherwise they must be rejected.

I understand the benefit of adding `Secure` and omit the `Domain` attribute, but **why** is the `Path=/` attribute a requirement? Is there a security advantage over explicitly set a more specific path? Does anybody knows where to find discussions or rationales behind this decision?

I would like to gain the advantages of using this prefix but my cookie is only used in some particular requests, so my cookie is now set with a `Path=/foo/bar` attribute. After seeing the requirement I started wondering if there is any security disadvantage that I'm unaware of over using the required `/`.

Answer (score 1):

To have a single canonical cookie.

With paths it is possible to have multiple cookies with the same name. E.g. you can have `CSRF-Token` on `Path=/foo/bar` and `CSRF-Token` on `Path=/something`, and these would be different cookies.

If the `CSRF-Token` cookie is HttpOnly, it couldn't be overwritten by JavaScript in an XSS attack. However, it would be possible to create a new `CSRF-Token` cookie with a different path. To prevent this, `__Host-` specifies fixed values for the path, which makes adding multiple `__Host-` cookies impossible.

[Here's a talk](https://youtu.be/njQcVWPB1is?t=2181) that goes into how setting a path can help in exploiting a vulnerability.